# Select rows from a dataframe based on the number of non-null columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4
0   NaN     D       NaN     I
1   NaN     NaN     F       J
2   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
3   A       E       NaN     NaN
4   NaN     NaN     G       NaN
5   NaN     NaN     NaN     K
6   B       NaN     NaN     NaN
7   NaN     NaN     H       NaN
8   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
9   C       NaN     NaN     NaN
```

I'm looking to keep the rows where there are at-least two non null entries:

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4
0   NaN     D       NaN     I
1   NaN     NaN     F       J
3   A       E       NaN     NaN
```

It's really easy to select all non-null columns using boolean indexing, but how would you generalize it to keep rows with >= x number of non-null entries?

Here is the code to create this dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'A', np.nan, np.nan, 'B', np.nan, np.nan, 'C'],
 'col2' : ['D', np.nan, np.nan, 'E', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
 'col3' : [np.nan, 'F', np.nan, np.nan, 'G', np.nan, np.nan, 'H', np.nan, np.nan],
 'col4' : ['I', 'J', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'K', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All kind of goodies in the options

```
In [20]: df.dropna(thresh=2)
Out[20]: 
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0  NaN    D  NaN    I
1  NaN  NaN    F    J
3    A    E  NaN  NaN
```

Here is an equivalent soln

```
df.loc[df.count(axis=1)>=2]
```

Comment: I was just writing up the `df.loc[df.notnull().sum(axis=1) >= 2]` approach, but yours is clearly better.  Although it could use a little more advertising -- I'm not sure I've seen that before!

Comment: sure want to add an example in missing.rst somewhere?

Comment: Wow, I wish I had known about the dropna thresh a long time ago. Awesome answer!